# How to install the neuralnet R package on a VPS from a local Windows machine?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am trying to train multiple ANNs in parallel in R. The problem is that I don't know how to install Neuralnet on the VPS from my local machine.
I'm looking for some instructions like the following, which works perfectly to install R and Future package on VPS:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK("VPS ip", user = "my_user")
clusterEvalQ(cl[1], { dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive=TRUE) })
clusterEvalQ(cl[1], { install.packages("future", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org") })
stopCluster(cl)
```

The script that implements parallel coding in R that I am testing is the following:

```
library(parallelly)
library(future)
library(parallel)
library(neuralnet)

data(iris)
head(iris)
nrow(iris)

red <- function(x) {
  fold.test <- sample(nrow(iris), nrow(iris) / 3)
  test <- iris[fold.test, ]
  train <- iris[-fold.test, ]
  ann <- neuralnet(as.numeric(Species) ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width +
                     Petal.Length + Petal.Width, train, hidden = c(10,5))
  ann
  output <- compute(ann, test[ , c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                                   "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")])

  result <- data.frame(
    Real = test$Species,
    Predicted = levels(iris$Species)[round(output$net.result)])
  result

  table(result$Predicted, result$Real)
  mse <-table(result$Predicted, result$Real)
  
  x
  
}

local_workers <- rep("localhost", times=3)
workers <- rep("VPS ip", times =1)
workers <- c(workers,local_workers)

system.time({
  cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(workers, user = "my_user")
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, "iris")
  resultados <- parSapply(cl, 1:20, red)})
  #resultados
stopCluster(cl)
```

And the error that occurs when running it is:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "neuralnet"
```

Comment: Install 'neuralnet' on the VPS just like you installed the 'future' package there.

Comment: Okay, I did it, but I get the following error:> clusterEvalQ(cl[1], { install.packages("neuralnet", repos = "https://github.com/bips-hb/neuralnet") })
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  one node produced an error: unable to install packages.

Comment: Try ssh:ing to that machine and install manually as you would do in any R session to see what the error is. You might be missing some system dependency, or something. This has nothing to do with parallel processing.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Even though I get a NULL value on installation, it works with: clusterEvalQ (cl [1], {install.packages ("neuralnet", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")})